# Where in Almaty can I live cheaply for 5 days?

Tags: accommodation, kazakhstan, almaty

I travel from my organization for 5 days into Kazakhstan, Almaty!
And i need cheaply place of residence and city trip! Who can help me with this information?

Comment: The worst hotel I ever stayed at was in Almaty.  And that was not exactly cheap @ > 120 USD per night!

Comment: Thanks for answer! Please tell me name of that hotel.

Comment: It was the Kazakhstan Hotel

Comment: The obvious first answer is Airbnb?

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith say the worst place you've ever stayed at, OP.... "interested" 

Comment: Do you have any local contacts who could advise you?

Comment: Google map gives you also hotel and hotel rates (and you can specify the period)

Comment: Have you tried to search on [booking.com](https://www.booking.com/)? They have a pretty wide range of options for Almaty. [Sky Hostel](https://www.booking.com/hotel/kz/sky-hostel-almaty.ru.html) in particular, is very cheap and has pretty good reviews. Depending on your needs you might want to stay in hotel, or rent an apartment, but this is going to be more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

I spent just over a week in Almaty back in August 2016 and i really like the city. I stayed in the [Hotel Tahar](http://tahar.kz/en/about/).

We stayed in an en-suite double room. It was basic but comfortable. It was pretty central, had parking availability and wifi and the staff spoke English. A large double room was about 20 USD per night.

I also spent a night at the [Golden Palace Hotel](https://goldenpalace.kz/en/). Which was much more luxurious, again with parking and Wifi. The Golden palace was somewhat more expensive, costing about 50 USD per night.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh I'd recommend avoiding the Chinese restaurant behind the hotel Tahar, or your 5 days in Almaty will be memorable for all the wrong reasons.

Comment: It will help a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. Hope you have a good time, I really enjoyed Almaty (Aside from the whole food poisoning thing). I hope to make it back there some day.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can book for somethings on Airbnb

Here is a search I just made for Example for the same Almaty

https://www.airbnb.com/s/Almaty--Almaty-Region--Kazakhstan/homes?query=Almaty%2C%20Almaty%20Region%2C%20Kazakhstan&checkin=2020-03-07&checkout=2020-03-12&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&guests=1&place_id=ChIJq8vFFn1ugzgRdm2YrY9mRD0&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Ffor_you&toddlers=0&source=mc_search_bar&search_type=unknown